# DialogFragment getActivity() returns null after fragment processes other data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, firebase, android-dialogfragment

I have read numerous `getActivity()` returns null questions, but I can't seem to find one that matches this scenario.

I have a `DialogFragment` that should do the following:

- Take input from the user
- Validate if input is correct and only proceed/dismiss dialog if so
- Make transactions/write data to Firebase database (this takes a second or so)
- Move to new activity and finish calling activity

I can get all of these pieces to work independently, but if I put the code to move to the new activity after the FB transactions are complete, I get an NPE when I set up my `startActivity()` intent.

From what I can tell, during the time the Firebase transactions are happening, the AlertDialog and DialogFragment are dismissed automatically and I can no longer get the context to set up my intent.

How do I get the proper activity or context to call `startActivity()`?
Thanks!

```
public class FinishedDialog extends DialogFragment {

private String pushId;

private AlertDialog alertDialog;

public static FinishedDialog newInstance(String PushId) {
    FinishedDialog frag = new FinishedDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("pushId", pushId);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    pushId = getArguments().getString("pushId");

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_finished, null))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.send_text_response, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // This will be overridden for data validations
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.continue_without_response, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finishListening();
                }
            })
            .setNeutralButton(R.string.listen_again, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     //Dismisses Dialog
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}

//This is set up so that if user hasn't entered data, positiveButton won't dismiss dialog
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    alertDialog = (AlertDialog)getDialog();
    if(alertDialog != null)
    {
        Button positiveButton = alertDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        final EditText responseEditText = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.entered_response);

        positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Boolean wantToCloseDialog = false;
                String enteredData = responseEditText.getText().toString();

                if (enteredData.length()>1) {
                    wantToCloseDialog = true;
                }

                if (wantToCloseDialog) {
                    alertDialog.dismiss(); //This line may be part of the problem, but I still get the NPE if I comment it out.
                    uploadResponseToFB(enteredData);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You didn't enter a response!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private void uploadResponseToFB(String response) {
    //Uploads some data to Firebase.
    finishListening();
}

private void finishListeningToStory() {
    //This method does a number of firebase transactions and data writes
    //The goBackToMainScreen() method is called onCompletion of the last data write.
}

private void goBackToMainScreen(){
    //Again, called onCompletion of last data write.
    //This crashes on next line due to NPE from getActivity(), but when I test this exact code without the FB transactions (closer to onCreateDialog() or onStart()) it works fine.
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ConversationListActivity.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I can tell, during the time the Firebase transactions are happening, the AlertDialog and DialogFragment are dismissed automatically and I can no longer get the context to set up my intent.

AFAIK This is the exact reason.

**Solution 1**

Pass the validated data to Hosting `Activity` and do firebase writes there. This way you will always have context to start another activity.

**Solution 2**

Don't dismiss `Dialog` (Show `ProgressBar` ) until your firebase writes are done and `ConversationListActivity` is started.

Comment: Initially, I wanted to do solution 1, but I was having a hard time getting the data validation to work right. Would I be better off going that route implementing a 'DialogListener'?      For solution 2, I tried displaying a 'ProgressDialog' spinner and keeping it active until 'ConversationListActivity' was started, but I had the same error.

Comment: I restructured my code to pass the validated data back to the hosting 'Activity'. This worked!